# WebView embedded youtube video does not accept full screen button?

Tags: android, html, webview, youtube

I have a WebView that is loading a WordPress website that has HTML5 youtube embedded videos within some articles. The videos will play fine but the full screen button does nothing but crash the videos. 
I have...
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

```
             web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
         web.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
         web.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
```

So it isn't the hardware acceleration.
Any ideas?

Comment: Anyone? I'm sure other people have this problem.